# Problem retrieving NSCell data via [NSTableColumn dataCellForRow]

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nscell, nstablecolumn

I am trying to retrieve a specific `NSCell` data from an `NSTableView` through `[NSTableColumn dataCellForRow]` but every time it shows different value for same row and same column. The data source remains the same at all time. The `NSTableView` is bound to an `NSArrayController` .Please if anyone can suggest a better way to do it correctly. And I don't want to implement those delegate methods. Let me know if you require more information.

Regards

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

Well, this is not a good idea to get data from a cell. Cells represent View concept in Model-View-Controller paradigm.
You should be able to access all the data that a cell can access, so get it from the primary data source.